# 503 Service Unavailable ERROR from Apache and Tomcat using mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I have this config on 000-default.conf the first application displayed cars correctly but not supercars which is with ajp protocol.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   ProxyPass        /cars http://localhost:8080/cars  
   ProxyPassReverse /cars http://localhost:8080/cars  
   <Location /cars>
        Require all granted
   </Location>

   ProxyPass        /supercars ajp://localhost:8009/supercars/
   ProxyPassReverse /supercars ajp://localhost:8009/supercars/

   <Location /supercars>
         Require all granted
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

And this config on server.xml

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" 
               proxyPort ="80" />

    <Connector port="8009"
               protocol="AJP/1.3" 
               redirectPort="8443"
               address="172.10.10.1" 
               secretRequired="false"
    />
```

My proxy.conf is:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset off
     Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) Server at 172.10.10.1 Port 80

I don't know where the error is, any help would be appreciated. thxx

I have opened the ports 8009 in the apache ports.conf file but it doesn't work, I have created another virtualhost with port 8009 but it doesn't work either, I don't know what it can be.

NEW UPDATE: solved i just put another port that was not 8009 exactly I put 8010 and it worked perfectly, u need to change 000-default.conf and server.xml ports and work for me

Comment: **1** You configured Apache to listen on port 80 (`<VirtualHost *:80>`). So if you do `http://exemple.com/supercars` the proxy will send it to AJP on port 8009.  In your Connector you redirect port 8009 to 8443.  Therefore Tomcat must answer on port 8443.  Test that first.  **2** Configure your apache logs to a higher level and validate your proxy.    **3** look at your tomcat logs to ensure you are actually connecting to ports you expect.  **4** you need to debug.

Comment: thanks for the help, I just put another port that was not 8009 exactly I put 8010 and it worked perfectly, I still do not know why the 8009 does not work and the 8010 if, anyway problem solved.